# VueJS listen to foreign event inside component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a custom Intercom launcher button component as follows:

```
export default {
  data  : function() {
    return ({
        open        : false,
        notif_count : 0,
    })
  },
  mounted           : function() {
    if (typeof Intercom !== 'undefined') {
        Intercom('onUnreadCountChange', function(count) {
            if (count) this.notif_count = count;
        });
        Intercom('onHide', function() {
            this.open = false;
        });
    }
  },
  computed      : {
    ...mapState({
        HIGHER  : (state) => state.intercom.higher,
    })
  },
}
```

Obviously the `onHide` method is not in the right place here, how can I `listen` to it to change `this.open`'s value if `onHide` triggers after the component has mounted?

Thank for your help!

Comment: You will have to use either arrow functions as event handlers (to have access to the component instance through `this`) or use component methods for the event handlers (which are already automatically bound to the component instance).

Comment: @IVOGELOV thank you for your answer! any chance you might give a code exemple?

Answer (score 0):

The variant with arrow functions

```js
export default 
{
  data() 
  {
    return {
        open        : false,
        notif_count : 0,
    };
  },
  mounted() 
  {
    if (typeof Intercom !== 'undefined') 
    {
        Intercom('onUnreadCountChange', (count) =>
        {
            if (count) this.notif_count = count;
        });
        Intercom('onHide', () =>
        {
            this.open = false;
        });
    }
  },
  computed: 
  {
    ...mapState({
        HIGHER  : (state) => state.intercom.higher,
    }),
  },
}
```

The variant with component methods

```js
export default 
{
  data() 
  {
    return {
        open        : false,
        notif_count : 0,
    };
  },
  mounted() 
  {
    if (typeof Intercom !== 'undefined') 
    {
        Intercom('onUnreadCountChange', this.onUnreadCountChange);
        Intercom('onHide', this.onHide);
    }
  },
  computed: 
  {
    ...mapState({
        HIGHER  : (state) => state.intercom.higher,
    }),
  },
  methods:
  {
    onUnreadCountChange(count)
    {
            if (count) this.notif_count = count;
    },
    onHide()
    {
            this.open = false;
    },
  }
}
```